# println needs a message - onActivityResult

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send message from my SecondActivity to FirstActivity to be printed. I am using startActivityForResult(intent, requestcode) to start the SecondActivity and then enter text and send the entered text to be displayed by FirstActivity using onActivityResult(). When I run the Activity and click on send I am getting error stating "println needs a message". The result is not getting delivered to the FirstActivity.

Below is the code:
FirstActivity:

```
private void StartSecondActivity() {

    Log.i(tag, "SecondActivity");

    Intent iSecond = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);

    startActivityForResult(iSecond, REQUEST_CODE);

}
```

SecondActivity:

```
private void eClicked() {

    Log.i(tag, "Clicked()");
    String mes = mEditText.getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, mes);

    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    Log.i(tag, mes);

    finish();
}
```

Here it does log correct message.

FirstActivity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.i(tag, "onActivityResult()");
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE ){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Intent inte = getIntent();
            String m = inte.getStringExtra(SecondActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            mTextView.setText(m);
        }
    }

}
```

It enters the onActivityResult and logs the message and then crashes with the below error message.

Error Message:

```
02-09 18:52:42.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 18:52:42.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1831): Process: droid.intentexp.intents, PID: 1831
02-09 18:52:42.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1831): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {droid.intentexp.intents/droid.intentexp.intents.FirstActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. Can someone please shed some light.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `data` intent **NOT** `getIntent()`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.i(tag, "onActivityResult()");
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE ) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String m = data.getStringExtra(SecondActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            mTextView.setText(m);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you somehow it just went out of my head :)

Answer (score 1):

initialize th string m with appropriate content.

> String m= " ";